# Problem Using UCREL USAS in Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory, spacy

I want to use USAS semantic tagger in Google Colab using the instructions [here](https://ucrel.github.io/pymusas/usage/how_to/tag_text)

```
pip install https://github.com/UCREL/pymusas-models/releases/download/en_dual_none_contextual-0.3.1/en_dual_none_contextual-0.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
import spacy
```

I install the package using the above code. And then run the following:

```
# We exclude the following components as we do not need them. 
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', exclude=['parser', 'ner'])
# Load the English PyMUSAS rule based tagger in a separate spaCy pipeline
english_tagger_pipeline = spacy.load('en_dual_none_contextual')
# Adds the English PyMUSAS rule based tagger to the main spaCy pipeline
nlp.add_pipe('pymusas_rule_based_tagger', source=english_tagger_pipeline)
```

I encounter the following error for the second line:

> TypeError: load_model_from_init_py() got an unexpected keyword
> argument 'enable'

Note that this error doesn't show up when running the same code on my local machine. Only in Google Colab...

Answer (score 0):

My sapCy version was too high. That's how I solved it:

```
!pip3 install spacy==3.2.3
```

Comment: pymusas-models caught up with spacy's 'enable' keyword 2023-03-06 and rebuilt all their taggers, so if you update them, you don't have to downgrade spaCy anymore